# Managing references to Singleton Classes in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, memory, singleton

I have a class in my app that extends the Application class. I have declared/named it in the Manifest.xml file. It basically initializes some stuff but more importantly gives me access to a serial port on the machine I'm programming on. Here is my question. I have an activity where I subclass this Application class. The Activity, lets call it Activity A initializes a variable that is declared in it's superclass (the one that subclasses Activity).

When I create an intent in Activity A meant to send the user to a different Activity, after calling startActivity(intent) I call finish(). Will that completely erase Activity A from memory, or, because in Activity A I reference a variable declared in the Application class, will this Activity A remain in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, actually when we use superclass properties in sub class it won't be more in memory. So when ever we call for finish() for activity. All declared variables and all references related to that Activity will be destroyed (removed from memory).